# How to correctly set kernel command parameter for sdboot

Tags: command-line, kernel

Thease are the kernel command line parameter

```
 Kernel command line (user set)

root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait console=ttyPS0,115200
```

I am trying to run linux from sd card, and the file system I have chosen is `initramfs`

given these facts, am I writing the kernel parameter correctly?

Comment: WHat happens when you try to boot with those parameters?

Comment: unable to mount SD card.